# PYTHON: searching for a word in a text file which includes spaces in between words

Tags: python, list, search

I'm stuck on how I would go about searching for a book title in a text file because the titles has spaces in between them.

This is the text file im trying to search:

```
#Listing showing sample book details 
#AUTHOR, TITLE, FORMAT, PUBLISHER, COST?, STOCK, GENRE
P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction
A. Pais, Subtle is the Lord, pb, OUP, 12.99, 2, biography
A. Calaprice, The Quotable Einstein, pb, PUP, 7.99, 6, science
M. Faraday, The Chemical History of a Candle, pb, Cherokee, 5.99, 1, science
C. Smith, Energy and Empire, hb, CUP, 60, 1, science
J. Herschel, Popular Lectures, hb, CUP, 25, 1, science
C.S. Lewis, The Screwtape Letters, pb, Fount, 6.99, 16, religion
J.R.R. Tolkein, The Hobbit, pb, Harper Collins, 7.99, 12, fiction
C.S. Lewis, The Four Loves, pb, Fount, 6.99, 7, religion
E. Heisenberg, Inner Exile, hb, Birkhauser, 24.95, 1, biography
G.G. Stokes, Natural Theology, hb, Black, 30, 1, religion
```

My code:

```
desc = input('Enter the title of the book you would like to search for: ')
for bookrecord in book_list:
    if desc in bookrecord:
        print('Book found')        
    else:
        print('Book not found')
        break
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: "im" is not a word. Please take a minute to use proper spelling before submitting your post.

Comment: Its `csv` file, By `import csv` you can use `csv.reader` and it will split your line by "," .

Comment: Could you provide an example please of the use of csv in this problem

Comment: @JJBANG458 If you found a useful post pls upvote and hit the tick mark

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def writeData(data):
    
    with open('file.txt', 'a') as w:
        w.write(data)

def searchData(title):
    data = ''
    title_list = []
    with open('file.txt') as r:
        data = r.read()
    
    title_list = data.split(', ')[1::6]
    print(title_list)
    
    stock = data.split(', ')[5::6]

    print(stock)
    
    if title in title_list:
        print('Book Found')

    else:
        print('Book Not Found')


writeData('P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction')
writeData('A. Pais, Subtle is the Lord, pb, OUP, 12.99, 2, biography')

searchData('Right Ho Jeeves')
```

Comment: just out of curiosity where in this code would you ask for a users input. Thanks for the answer !!

Comment: @JJBANG458 add title = input() and place the title inside `seardhData` function call + if you found it helpful upvote and hit the tick mark

Comment: i did that and it worked!!! i will upvote and tick. Also from that book title i need to acess the stock number and give an option to add more stock, if you dont mind dude can you help

Comment: Yeah dude that is kinda working, its when i search for a title im not sure how i can access the stock level for that specific title and then add an option to increase the stock level for that title

Comment: Unfortuantely i cant add another question because im so new to the site

Comment: @JJBANG458 There is no limit to the number of questions that you can ask. If you post the question post me the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65159107/how-to-increase-stock-level-in-my-text-file-form-a-title-description-search

Answer (score -1):

You can use the split function to remove the spaces:

```
handle = open("book list.txt")#Open a file handle of the given file
            
for lines in handle:#A variable 'lines' that will iterate through all the variables in the file
    words = lines.split(,)#splits the file text into separate words and removes extra spaces.(the comma tells it to split where there are commas)
        
desc = input('Enter the title of the book you would like to search for: ')
        
for bookrecord in words:
    if desc in bookrecord:
        print('Book found')
else:
    print('Book not found')
         break
```

Fix the indentation in the code before running it, or it will give an error.

Comment: i attempted it but when is search for 'The Hobbit' it still outputs book not found

Answer (score -1):

If your file is csv then:

```
import pandas as pd

inp = input("Enter the books name: ")

bk = pd.read_csv('book_list.csv')#enter your file name
for row in bk.iterrows():
    if inp in row:
        print("Book found")
    else:
        print("Book not found")
```

Note: This will only work if your file is csv

Comment: is there an easier way to do this as i cant use pandas for the assessment

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to open a csv file without any modules...

Answer (score -1):

You can read your file into a **python list** so that each time you want to find a single book name or author from the file, you don't have to reload the file again and again.

```py
with open("file", "r") as file:
    data = file.readlines()
```

This makes your code fast, if the file is large! Now, you can simply find what you want to find:

```py
text_to_find = "C. Smith"

for idx, line in enumerate(data):
    if text_to_find in line:
        print(f"{text_to_find} FOUND AT {idx} LINE")
```

Note the use of *f-string*!